# $\left \lfloor \log_bx \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \log_b\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \right \rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What conditions on real number  $ \;\; b > 1\;\;$ is necessary and sufficient to guarantee that $\left \lfloor \log_bx \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \log_b\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \right \rfloor$ for any real number $x \geq 1$.

If we assume $\;\; b = m+f\;\;$ where $m$ is an integer and fraction $f$ $< 1$.
Setting $x = b$,

$LHS = 1$

$RHS = \left \lfloor \log_{m+f}m \right \rfloor = 0$

$\Rightarrow b $ must be an integer $\geq 2$

How to prove further that for any integer $\;\;b \geq 2 \;\; $ and for any real $x$ above identity holds?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that
$$\lfloor \log_b x\rfloor>\lfloor\log_b\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor$$

Then there is some integer $n$ such that
$$\lfloor x\rfloor <b^n\le x$$

This can not happen, for example, if $b$, or $x$, is a positive integer. But making $b=2.5$, $x=6.3$ we have
$$\lfloor\log_bx\rfloor=2$$
$$\lfloor\log_b\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor=1$$

Comment: I'm not native speaker so I don't know if "is" in "is a positive integer" should be "are". Please feel free to fix it.

Comment: and there is no possibility of LHS < RHS , so this completes the proof? Am I right?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.